# Passing props in react-native-flux-router

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

So I'm still a bit new to React Native, but I've got an app working nearly how I want it to.  I have `App.js` which uses the `TabBarIOS` component to display my tabbed navigation at the bottom of the screen. When you touch a tab, the state updates and the relevant content is loaded and displayed:

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TabBarIOS, Platform, Image } from 'react-native';

import IconII from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import IconMCI from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';

import Colors from './Colors';
import RouterItem1 from './routers/RouterItem1';
import RouterItem2 from './routers/RouterItem2';
import RouterHome from './routers/RouterHome';
import Settings from './components/Settings';

class FooterNav extends Component {

  state = {
    selectedTab: 'home',
  };

  handleClick = (routeData) => {
    console.log('This has received data', routeData);
    this.setState({ selectedTab: routeData });
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  renderCurrentView() {
    switch (this.state.selectedTab) {
      case 'home':
        return (
          <RouterHome handleClick={this.handleClick} />
        );
      case 'item2':
        return (
          <RouterItem2 />
        );
      case 'item1':
        return (
          <RouterItem1 />
        );
      case 'settings':
        return (
          <Settings />
        );
      default:
        return false;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TabBarIOS
        unselectedTintColor={Colors.third}     //Unselected labels
        unselectedItemTintColor={Colors.third} //Unselected icons
        tintColor={Colors.brandPrimary}        //Selected
        barTintColor={Colors.light}            //Bar background
      >
        <IconII.TabBarItem
          title="Home"
          iconName="ios-home-outline"
          selectedIconName="ios-home"
          selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'home'}
          receiveData={this.receiveData}
          onPress={() => {
            this.setState({
              selectedTab: 'home',
            });
          }}
        >
          {this.renderCurrentView()}
        </IconII.TabBarItem>
        <TabBarIOS.Item
          icon={require('./images/item2-icon-line@3x.png')}
          selectedIcon={require('./images/item2-icon-selected@3x.png')}
          title="item2"
          selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'item2'}
          onPress={() => {
            this.setState({
              selectedTab: 'item2',
            });
          }}
        >
          {this.renderCurrentView()}
        </TabBarIOS.Item>
        <IconMCI.TabBarItem
          title="item1"
          iconName="cookie"
          selectedIconName="cookie"
          selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'item1'}
          onPress={() => {
            this.setState({
              selectedTab: 'item1',
            });
          }}
        >
          {this.renderCurrentView()}
        </IconMCI.TabBarItem>
        <IconII.TabBarItem
          title="More"
          iconName="ios-more-outline"
          selectedIconName="ios-more"
          selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'settings'}
          onPress={() => {
            this.setState({
              selectedTab: 'settings',
            });
          }}
        >
          {this.renderCurrentView()}
        </IconII.TabBarItem>
      </TabBarIOS>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = FooterNav;
```

`react-native-router-flux` is a great plugin, once it pulls in a router the flow is exactly what I want it to be.  The only problem I have is with the `<RouterHome>` module:

**RouterHome.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Scene, Router } from 'react-native-router-flux';

import styles from '../Styles';
import { content } from '../content.js';

import AnotherScene from '../components/pages/AnotherScene';
import Home from '../components/Home';

const RouterHomeComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Router
      sceneStyle={styles.sceneStyle}
      navigationBarStyle={styles.navBar}
      titleStyle={styles.navBarTitle}
      barButtonIconStyle={styles.barButtonIconStyle}
    >
      <Scene
        key="Home"
        component={Home}
        title={content.heading}
        hideNavBar
      />
      <Scene
        key="AnotherScene"
        component={AnotherScene}
        title='title'
        hideNavBar={false}
      />
    </Router>
  );
};

export default RouterHomeComponent;
```

The default view that is loaded is the `<Home>` module:

**Home.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

import styles from '../Styles';
import { content } from '../content.js';

class Home extends Component {

  displayItem1 = () => {
    this.props.handleClick('item1');
  }
  displayItem2 = () => {
    this.props.handleClick('item2');
  }
  displayAnotherScene() {
    Actions.AnotherScene();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.viewWrapperHome}>

        <Text style={styles.heading}>{content.greeting}</Text>

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.displayItem1}>
          <Text>First item</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.displayItem2}>
          <Text>Second item</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.displayAnotherScene}>
          <Text>Another scene</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

So what I expect to happen is that if the user clicks on the first two buttons displayed on the screen (`First item`/`Second item`), the prop will be passed back to `App.js`, the state will change and the scene will be updated.  It basically is an alternative way of navigating without using the footer menu.

I know that this would work without using the `react-native-router-flux` module as I had it running before I added it in.  The problem is that I really need it to handle the other pages from the `<Home>` module (many more to add).

Can anyone suggest a way I can pass back the props through the router back to my `App.js`?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and do not use `react-native-router-flux`, the library builds upon deprecated code and its community will slowly transition to `react-navigation`. Now, `react-navigation` is not a full solution either but will get most of community attention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, so I actually figured this out - it turned out to totally be my fault; the props weren't getting passed to `RouterHome` and so they got lost either side.  The new `RouterHome` looks like this:

**RouterHome.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Scene, Router } from 'react-native-router-flux';

import styles from '../Styles';
import { content } from '../content.js';

import AnotherScene from '../components/pages/AnotherScene';
import Home from '../components/Home';

const RouterHomeComponent = (props) => {      <---Didn't add props
  return (
    <Router
      sceneStyle={styles.sceneStyle}
      navigationBarStyle={styles.navBar}
      titleStyle={styles.navBarTitle}
      barButtonIconStyle={styles.barButtonIconStyle}
    >
      <Scene
        key="Home"
        component={Home}
        title={content.heading}
        hideNavBar
        handleClick={props.handleClick}     <---Didn't pass props
      />
      <Scene
        key="AnotherScene"
        component={AnotherScene}
        title='title'
        hideNavBar={false}
      />
    </Router>
  );
};

export default RouterHomeComponent;
```

I've marked the two changes I made.  Hopefully this will help someone! :)